# Nginx reverse proxy + CloudFlare Geolocation Service

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

In our environment, we are using Nginx as a reverse proxy to our Apache application server. In need for a Geolocation service, we decided to use CloudFlare's IP_Country service.

We are being able to receive the IP_Country HTTP parameter, but we are being unable to pass it to Apache.

We tried setting the following rule, but it does not seem to work:

```
proxy_set_header        HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY       $sent_http_CF_IPCountry;
```

I would appreciate any help in regards to passing custom HTTP parameters from Nginx to Apache.

Best Regards,
Hex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `$sent_http_CF_IPCountry`, use `$http_cf_ipcountry`. The latter one refers to the incoming HTTP header sent by the client.

Comment: It's not working either. One thing that I forgot to mention is that the HTTP parameter is coming as "CF-IPCountry" (with - dash) but according to Nginx documentation, dashes need to be converted to underscore and uppercase characters need to converted to lowercase in config files.

Comment: Edited answer: Try to use all-lower case form.